# Auto fill find bar with highlighted text?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

When searching on the page it would be great if you could auto fill the find bar with highlighted text as was proposed here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sS43zI263q0

Is there already an extension that does this?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 indeed a duplicate. Should I close this or keep it for reference?

Comment: you can just leave it, it'll get closed eventually ('Flag' a mod and request it be closed to speed up the process if you'd like :) ).